# Symfony 4 won't translate validator messages and always shows the English default

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Hi I'm French and I try with Symfony 4 to have the translation on validator messages/

```
private function validationAction($iban)
{
    $validator = Validation::createValidator();

    $ibanClient = $iban;
    $constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
        'iban' => array(
            new Assert\NotBlank(array('message' => 'Champs obligatoire')),
            new Assert\Iban()
        ),
    ));

    return $errors = $validator->validate(
        array('iban' => $ibanClient),
        $constraint
    );
}
```

I installed the translation system using

`composer require symfony/translation`

Now if i put $iban = "FR00"
this is the response :

```
This is not a valid International Bank Account Number (IBAN).
```

I saw in

> vendor/symfony/validator/Resources/translations/validators.fr.xlf

the file already exist, and i have configured the locale in

> config/packages/framework.yaml

```
framework:
secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
default_locale: fr
```

And in

> config/services.yaml

```
parameters:
locale: 'fr'
```

I tried to create file in

> translations/validators.fr.yml

but no change.
Please Help me, thanks

Comment: By calling `Validation::createValidator()` you create a new instance of the validator which is not configured to deal with translations. Looking at the filenames in your description it seems like you are running a full Symfony application. In this case, you do not need to create the validator on your own, but simply inject the `validator` service.

Comment: Ok i will try and let you know. thks

Comment: So I have a little form with just 1 input text, with ajax i send the user's data + this input text to my controller. I have to check if this required field is valid (is Iban, is not blank, is min length...). How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is my code that works :

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/rib/add", name="rib_add", condition="request.isXmlHttpRequest()")
 */
public function rib_add(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator)
{
    try {
        $errors = $validator->validate(
            array('iban' => $request->get('')),
            new Assert\Collection(array(
                'iban' => array(
                    new Assert\NotBlank(),
                    new Assert\Iban(),
                    new Assert\Length(array('min' => 5)),
                ),
            )));
        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            throw new \Exception($errors[0]->getMessage());
        }

        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Ajout du RIB ok',
            'data'    => [],
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {

        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => false,
            'code'    => $exception->getCode(),
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        ]);
    }
}
```